# How to check if a date is at least one day in the past with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

How does one generally check if a random date is at least one day (24hrs) in the past with momentjs?

Something like:

```
const today = moment()
const isAtLeastADayAgo = today.subtract(dateToCheck) > 1 // ??
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)

```js
function isADayAgo(input){
  let yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'd');
  return input.isBefore(yesterday);
}

const isAtLeastADayAgo = isADayAgo(moment());
console.log(isAtLeastADayAgo);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can use [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) limiting granularity to days:

```js
const today = moment();
const dateToCheck = moment().subtract(3, 'd');
const isAtLeastADayAgo = today.diff(dateToCheck, 'd') > 1;
console.log(isAtLeastADayAgo);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

i would suggest you to do it with plain javascript Date constructor.

```
var today =  new Date();
var pastDate = // some past date
// 86400 seconds in 24hrs
// getTime() will return you date in milliseconds
if(86400000 < today.getTime()-pastDate.getTime()) will return true if past date is older than 24Hrs.
```

Comment: A vote from me, but I'd code it as `if (today - pastDate > 86400000)`, though it may be inaccurate over a daylight saving boundary. To fix that: `if (pastDate < today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1))`;-)

Comment: @RobG i just followed the *eslint* recomendation to write constant on right hand side. BTW i liked ur answer (cleaner).

Answer (score 0):

```
const isAtLeastADayAgo = moment().subtract(1,'days')>dateToCheck
```